# Java Lambda function connnect MSK cluster timeout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I have created a java lambda function within same vpc, security group of MSK cluster. But when lambda execute the code, in cloudwatch:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
```

My java creating topic code like this:

```
public String handleRequest(SQSEvent input, Context context) {

        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        if(bootStrapServer == null) {
            System.out.println("missing boot strap server env var");
            return "Error, bootStrapServer env var missing";
        }

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer);
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "java-data-screaming-demo-lambda");
        props.put(AdminClientConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "PLAINTEXT");

        try {
            this.createTopic("TestLambdaTopic", props, logger);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log("err in creating topic: " + gson.toJson(e));
        }


        return "Ok";
    }

    public void createTopic(String topicName, Properties properties, LambdaLogger logger ) throws Exception {
        try (Admin admin = Admin.create(properties)) {
            int partitions = 1;
            short replicationFactor = 2;
            NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, partitions, replicationFactor);

            List<NewTopic> topics = new ArrayList<NewTopic>();
            topics.add(newTopic);

            CreateTopicsResult result = admin.createTopics(topics);
            // get the async result for the new topic creation
            KafkaFuture<Void> future = result.values().get(topicName);

            // call get() to block until topic creation has completed or failed
            future.get();
            if (future.isDone()) {
                logger.log("future is done");
            }

            logger.log("what is result from create topics: " + gson.toJson(result));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This error is common if `bootStrapServer` is wrong, the network is not configured for connection, or Kafka requires authentication. Does your code work outside of Lambda?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah, thank you for replying. I have the bootstrap server setup right, I think maybe it is because some aws setup thing? I have the MSK cluster security setting to be Unauthenticated access. And get the bootstrap server from View client information

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure it out, it is the vpc. I used companies production vpc and its subnets or security groups setting have problem.

What is weird is that deploy a client EC2 in the vpc can access the cluser, just following aws msk tutorial and that client EC2 can create topics, send and receive messages.

But deploy a Lambda function in the vpc is not working somehow. I will update in here if I find out why later. Currently I use the default vpc, which dont have much security settings, and it works. Lambda -> MSK cluster can create topic.